# Can I configure Azure APIM to respect Cache-Control headers?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to add caching to the application we have exposed over APIM. My preferable way would be to add cache-control headers to the responses from the client. Can I configure Azure APIM to respect Cache-Control headers that are part of the response from the underlying service? All the documentaition I can find is how to configure all caching policies and rules in APIM, where I just want a simple rule that says "respect the headers from the underlying service".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in policy just for that, but you can craft such mechanism yourself using the policies you have available. Here is the [example how to control API Management response cache duration with Cache-Control headers sent by the backend service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies#example-using-policy-expressions)
By looking at the example above you can try to handle other directives.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know why it isn’t configure to respect the http headers? I mean, if you added the headers you would expect all downstream parties to respect them.

Comment: @TomasJansson this is just the way it is, I have not developed APIM ;)